# auto execute a terminal command in raspberry pi startup

Tags: raspbian, boot, script

I am working on a pi project which uses audio out through HDMI. I am using respeaker mic for audio in. My problem is everytime when I startup the pi, the default audio is analog. I need to change it to HDMI by logging in and running

```
amixer -c 0 cset numid=3 2
```

using the terminal. I tried adding this line in a file sound.sh and when i execute the shell script using terminal it executes fine and changes to hdmi audio. My question is how to add this shell script to startup of pi, so that i dont have to run the script manually. i tried adding it to /etc/rc.local file. But doesnt seem to work. I am not sure of the exact command too. i tried:

```
sudo sh /home/pi/sound.sh &
sudo /home/pi/sound.sh &
/home/pi/sound.sh &
sh /home/pi/sound.sh &
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You probably need to add the full path to 'amixer' in your sound.sh script.

Answer (score 2):

Raspbian comes with **systemd** and old style *SysV rc.local* is only emulated by it. It is known that it has limitations and will be supported less step by step. The developer write in [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/):

> In general, it's a good idea to write proper unit files with properly defined dependncies, and avoid making use of rc.local.

Here is a simple Unit file that may work. If not, tell it. Create it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl edit --force set_audio.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Switch audio out to HDMI
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/amixer cset numid=3 2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable the new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable set_audio.service
```

According to [Audio configuration](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/audio-config.md) you also may have to set `hdmi_drive=2` in `/boot/config.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Add your `amixer -c 0 cset numid=3 2` a line to /etc/rc.local (just before the `exit 0` line).

That gets run once at boot time.

If you add it as `amixer -c 0 cset numid=3 2 > /tmp/amixer.out 2> /tmp/amixer.err` you'll be able to look at those files to see any error messages that may be issued by your command.